# Win32Exception: The specified service does not exist as an installed service

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I am working on windows service. In `catch` block getting exception while stopping service.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Service AirService was not
>   found on computer'
>
> InnerException- Win32Exception: The specified service does not exist as
>   an installed service.

This is my code

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //WriteToFile("Simple Service Error on: {0} " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
    //Stop the Windows Service.
    using (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController serviceController = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("AirService"))
    {
        serviceController.Stop();
    }
}
```

How can I check if service installed or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a list of installed services from ServiceController.GetServices().

```
    public static bool CheckServiceInstalled(string serviceToFind)
    {
        ServiceController[] servicelist = ServiceController.GetServices();
        foreach (ServiceController service in servicelist)
        {
            if (service.ServiceName == serviceToFind)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```